# DB2 timestamp format in PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, db2, odbc

I've got PHP talking to DB2 (v10.5 on Ubuntu 14.04) via ODBC and the EasySoft driver. I'm having trouble with the timestamp format when using `select id from new table(insert ....)` format for query.

Here is my table:

```
$create = "create table permissions (
        id int not null generated always as identity,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        display_name varchar(255),
        description varchar(255),
        created_at timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
        updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp not null
      )";

$pdo->prepare($create)->execute();
```

That works fine, as does the original PDO insert:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("insert into permissions (name, display_name, description, updated_at, created_at) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sth->execute([
"client_admin_dashboard",
"Client Admin Dashboard",
"Can view overview of team",
"2015-07-09 14:10:50.000",
"2015-07-09 14:10:50.000"
]);
```

But if I try to do the `select id` style query (with the same bindings):

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("select id from new table(insert into permissions (name, display_name, description, updated_at, created_at) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?))");
```

I get the following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: -180 
[Easysoft][ODBC-DB2 Driver][DRDA] SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect. SQLSTATE=22007 (SQLExecute[4294967116] at 
/build/php5-RvVZKb/php5-5.6.10+dfsg/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)' in 
/home/vagrant/repos/throwaway/test.php on line 65

PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: -180 [Easysoft][ODBC-DB2 Driver][DRDA] SQL0180N  
The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect. SQLSTATE=22007 
(SQLExecute[4294967116] at /build/php5-RvVZKb/php55.6.10+dfsg/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254) in /home/vagrant/repos/throwaway/test.php
on line 65

Call Stack:
    0.0007     226848   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/repos/throwaway/test.php:0
    0.1021     230648   2. PDOStatement->execute()     /home/vagrant/repos/throwaway/test.php:65
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

EDIT:

Moving the variables into the query itself instead of using bindings works fine:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("select id from new table(insert into permissions (name,
display_name, description, updated_at, created_at) values ( 
'client_admin_dashboard', 'Client Admin Dashboard', 'Can view overview of 
team', '2015-07-09 14:10:50.000', '2015-07-09 14:10:50.000'))")->execute();
```

Comment: When ODBC is applying the parameters to a prepared statement it's going to check formats.  It's expecting a timestamp but getting something that doesn't match what ODBC thinks a timestamp should look like.  If you can prepare it somehow treating it as a string it should work, and if not you might have to just put it in the sql inline.

Comment: Agreed. I just don't understand why the former is "changing" or becoming invalid for whatever reason when the normal insert is wrapped with the `select id from new table (INSERT...)`. It seems to me that that shouldn't change how the PDO bindings are interpreted. Very confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver vendor issued a fix. They had trouble tracking down the problem:

> It took a bit of tracking down because the issue only occurs on your PHP version with that exact PDO-ODBC version. It doesn't give the same results if you are out by even .0.1 of a version.

Answer (score 0):

It is truly weird. If I try to execute your command statically from CLP, everything works fine:

```
select id from new table(insert into permissions (name, display_name, description, updated_at, created_at) values ( 'client_admin_dashboard', 'Client Admin Dashboard', 'Can view overview of team', '2015-07-09 14:10:50.000', '2015-07-09 14:10:50.000'))

ID
-----------
          2

 1 record(s) selected.
```

Could it be that the ODBC driver (or regional settings) is somehow messing up the timestamp format? In order to confirm that, the only way I can think of is take DB2 CLI and server traces which should show the timestamp data received from the client.

On a side note, I have noticed that the order of `created_at` and `updated_at` is reversed in the failing case:

```
...(insert into permissions (..., updated_at, created_at)...
```

A stupid question, but what happens if you fix the order?

Comment: swapping the order didn't change things. If I just execute the statement, without passing through bindings, it works (have updated question).

Comment: Thanks for the updated question. I think this pretty much proves that the ODBC driver is somehow messing up with the timestamp format. It has been some time since I played with ODBC, but I vaguely recall it respects the regional settings of the machine, or in some cases there are configuration variables for this. Have you explored this avenue?

Comment: I'm working with the ODBC driver vendor on this. Fingers crossed!